# Plot rectangle with multiple points. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, google-maps, geometry, polygon

[this is precisely what I want multiple markers and covering them is a rectangle polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF0mp.png)I am having multiple latitude and longitude points. I need to plot a polygon in my Windows form application covering all those specified. Something like this.

It consists of a polygon and rectangle. Avoid polygon I just want the rectangle.
[image: 2]

Comment: You want to color some pixels? Use graphics.FillRectangle(semitranparentBrush, x, y, w, h) and/or graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, x, y, w, h) e.g. in the Paint event or on a Bitmap..

Comment: I edited the question. Please check again.

Comment: what is the relation between the markers and the rectangle? Do you want to find and draw the minimal rectangle? Put the markers in a list and use linq to find the minimum and maximum x and y values..: `List<PointF> markers = new List<PointF>() { p1,p2,p3,p4....};
 float xLeft = markers.Min(x => x.X); float yTop = markers.Min(x => x.Y);..`

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by @Taw, you can draw the rectangle with following co-ordinates:

```
List<PointF> ptlist = new List<PointF>();

// Add points to the list here

ptlist.Sort((p1, p2) => (p1.X.CompareTo(p2.X))); //Sort by X
float left = ptlist[0].X
float right = ptlist[ptlist.Count - 1].X

ptlist.Sort((p1, p2) => (p1.Y.CompareTo(p2.Y))); //Sort by Y
float top = ptlist[0].Y
float bottom = ptlist[ptlist.Count - 1].Y

// Use left, top and right, bottom to draw your rectangle.
```

Instead of sort, you may also write a simple code to find minimum and maximum of the list for efficiency.

Comment: Note that, depending on the number of elements, a sort is much less efficient than calling Min and Max.